# How to convert Int to Double in my Array assignment

Tags: java

So I am having some trouble with an assignment of mine.  This is the question proposed to us:
Write your code in the file Averages.java. The answers should be outputted using the IO module as previously described.

Your assignment is to calculate averages given a list of input. First ask the users how many numbers (doubles) she will enter. Then prompt for that many numbers.

Then output the following values min,max, sum, mean, median, mode - in that order. For the purposes of this exercise, you may assume that either 1 mode exists or no modes exist. (e.g. in {1,3,3,4,4}, there is no mode since there are 2 3's and 2 4's, but {1,3,3,4} has a mode of 3). If no mode exists, you can output the String "none".

The median is determined by finding the middle number. If no such number exists, it is calculated by taking the mean of the 2 middle numbers.

Hint: In order to accomplish median/mode calculations it might be useful for you to keep the list of numbers in some sorted order. i.e. on every insertion, place the number in the "correct" place.

Example (note commented descriptions should not be printed - they are for your information only):

```
10
5.8
1.4
2.3
1.4
1.4
1.0
3.2
10.5
11.0
2.0

RESULT: 1.0      //min
RESULT: 11.0     //max
RESULT: 40.0     //sum
RESULT: 4.0     //mean
RESULT: 2.15     //median
RESULT: 1.4      //mode
```

This is my current code:

```
public class Averages{
    public static void main(String []args){
        int n, c, d, swap,sum=0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input number of integers to sort");
        n = in.nextInt();
        int array[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter " + n + " integers");
        for (c = 0; c < n; c++){
            array[c] = in.nextInt();
            sum=sum+array[c];
        }

        for (c = 0; c < ( n - 1 ); c++) {
            for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++) {
                if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For descending order use < */
                {
                    swap = array[d];
                    array[d] = array[d+1];
                    array[d+1] = swap;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sorted array:");
        for (c = 0; c < ( n - 1 ); c++) {
            System.out.println(array[c]);
        }


        System.out.println("Sum="+sum);
        System.out.println("Max="+array[n-1]);
        System.out.println("Min="+array[0]);
        System.out.println("Mean="+sum/n);

        double median = 0;
        double mid=0;
        if(n%2 == 0)
        {
            int temp=(n/2)-1;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                if(temp==i || (temp+1)==i)
                {
                    mid=mid+array[i];
                }
            }
            mid=mid/2;
            System.out.println("Median value is: "+mid);
        }
        else
        {
            int temp=(n/2);
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                if(temp==i)
                {
                    mid=array[i];
                    System.out.println("Median value: "+mid);
                }
            }
        }
//Mode calculation
        int i,j,z, tmp, maxCount, modeValue;
        int[] tally=new int[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n-i;j++)
            {
                if(j+1!=n)
                {
                    if(array[j]>array[j+1])
                    {
                        tmp=array[j];
                        array[j]=array[j+1];
                        array[j+1]=tmp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for(z=i+1;z<n;z++)
            {
                if(array[i]==array[z])
                {
                    tally[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
        maxCount = 0;
        modeValue = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <n; i++)
        {
            if (tally[i] > maxCount)
            {
                maxCount = tally[i];
                modeValue = array[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Mode value is :"+modeValue);
    }
}
```

As you can see from my code, it can only run Int's not Double's.  I've tried rewriting all the Int's as Double's but that doesn't work.  Can anyone help me with a way to fix my program to accept and output double's?

This is what I have tried:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Averages{
public static void main(String []args){
double n, c, d, swap,sum=0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input number of Doubles to sort");
n = in.nextDouble();
double array[] = new double[n];
System.out.println("Enter " + n + " doubles");
for (c = 0; c < n; c++){
array[c] = in.nextDouble();
sum=sum+array[c];
}

for (c = 0; c < ( n - 1 ); c++) {
for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++) {
if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For descending order use < */
{
swap = array[d];
array[d] = array[d+1];
array[d+1] = swap;
}
}
}
System.out.println("Sorted array:");
for (c = 0; c < ( n - 1 ); c++) {
System.out.println(array[c]);
}
  
  
System.out.println("Sum="+sum);
System.out.println("Max="+array[n-1]);
System.out.println("Min="+array[0]);
System.out.println("Mean="+sum/n);
  
double median = 0;
double mid=0;
if(n%2 == 0)
{
double temp=(n/2)-1;
for(double i=0;i<n;i++)
{
if(temp==i || (temp+1)==i)
{
mid=mid+array[i];
}
}
mid=mid/2;
System.out.println("Median value is: "+mid);
}
else
{
double temp=(n/2);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
if(temp==i)
{
mid=array[i];
System.out.println("Median value: "+mid);
}
}
}
//Mode calculation
double i,j,z, tmp, maxCount, modeValue;
double[] tally=new double[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<n-i;j++)
{
if(j+1!=n)
{
if(array[j]>array[j+1])
{
tmp=array[j];
array[j]=array[j+1];
array[j+1]=tmp;
}
}
}
}
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
for(z=i+1;z<n;z++)
{
if(array[i]==array[z])
{
tally[i]++;
}
}
}
maxCount = 0;
modeValue = 0;
for (i = 0; i <n; i++)
{
if (tally[i] > maxCount)
{
maxCount = tally[i];
modeValue = array[i];
}
}
System.out.println("Mode value is :"+modeValue);
}
}
```

Comment: "that doesn't work" doesn't tell us *anything* about what problems you've run into. Are you also using `nextDouble` instead of `nextInt`? Additionally, your code isn't Javascript so please don't put it in a Javascript snippet, and please try to format your code with proper indentation too in future. (Another user has done it for you this time...)

Comment: Also put every operation(max, min, average, sum) in a different function and make it return the result. Call the functions in main and print results there. It will make the code more readable.

Comment: Im saying "that doesnt work" in the sense that I know something doesn't work. The question I am asking is how do I convert an array that inputs/outputs ints to an array that inputs/outputs doubles.  The code works 100% fine with ints as is, I just don't have any idea how to get it to work with doubles.

Comment: Your assignment says you have to take doubles, yet you scan for integers and prompt for integers.

Comment: RIght, as I said under my code above, I've tried just replacing all INT's with Double's and it doesn't work. I've added my edited code, the errors are that it cannot convert int to double

Comment: See my answer. Casting everything to doubles is incorrect, because array size and indexes require an int. The only doubles should be your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one existing problem in your code missing last item while printing sorted array.

for (c = 0; c < ( n - 1 ) ; c++) {

instead use

for (c = 0; c < n ; c++) {

For double problem, dont change everything from int to double.

1. Change to double **only** array and variable used to store result (swap,sum etc) and temp variable to store data.
2. Keep variable used for array indexing (n, d, c) as Int.
3. Read actual data element as Double using nextDouble.

   array[c] = in.nextDouble();

Code with minimal change to your code. Please create method for separate function like min(), max(), sort() etc.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Averages{
    public static void main(String []args){
        double swap,sum=0;
        int d, c, n;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input number of integers to sort");
        n = in.nextInt();
        double array[] = new double[n];
        System.out.println("Enter " + n + " integers");
        for (c = 0; c < n; c++){
            array[c] = in.nextDouble();
            sum=sum+array[c];
        }

        for (c = 0; c < ( n - 1 ); c++) {
            for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++) {
                if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For descending order use < */
                {
                    swap = array[d];
                    array[d] = array[d+1];
                    array[d+1] = swap;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sorted array:");
        for (c = 0; c < ( n - 1 ); c++) {
            System.out.println(array[c]);
        }


        System.out.println("Sum="+sum);
        System.out.println("Max="+array[n-1]);
        System.out.println("Min="+array[0]);
        System.out.println("Mean="+sum/n);

        double median = 0;
        double mid=0;
        if(n%2 == 0)
        {
            int temp=(n/2)-1;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                if(temp==i || (temp+1)==i)
                {
                    mid=mid+array[i];
                }
            }
            mid=mid/2;
            System.out.println("Median value is: "+mid);
        }
        else
        {
            int temp=(n/2);
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                if(temp==i)
                {
                    mid=array[i];
                    System.out.println("Median value: "+mid);
                }
            }
        }
//Mode calculation
        int i,j,z, maxCount;
        double tmp, modeValue;
        int[] tally=new int[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n-i;j++)
            {
                if(j+1!=n)
                {
                    if(array[j]>array[j+1])
                    {
                        tmp=array[j];
                        array[j]=array[j+1];
                        array[j+1]=tmp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for(z=i+1;z<n;z++)
            {
                if(array[i]==array[z])
                {
                    tally[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
        maxCount = 0;
        modeValue = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <n; i++)
        {
            if (tally[i] > maxCount)
            {
                maxCount = tally[i];
                modeValue = array[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Mode value is :"+modeValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just cast the ints to doubles whenever you do a calculation involving rational numbers, like so: 
`System.out.println("Mean=" + ((double)sum / n));`
This effectively temporarily turns them into doubles.

Comment: This doesn't address double inputs. If you cast doubles as ints they will lose the decimals.

Comment: I was assuming all the inputs should have been integers, since that's what the prompt displays.

Answer (score 0):

The input is wrong...

```
10 5.8 1.4 2.3 1.4 1.4 1.0 3.2 10.5 11.0 2.0
```

Since you said:

```
System.out.println("Enter " + n + " integers");
```

And 5.8, 1.4 etc.. are not integers...

Put this on line 12:

```
array[c] = in.next();
```

instead of:

```
        array[c] = in.nextInt();
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `nextDouble()` as @Jon Skeet suggested.

Comment: The input you are referencing is what possible inputs could be.  It is unrelated to my code but should be inputs my code is capable of working with.  The issue is I don't know how to get my code to work with doubles instead of ints.

Comment: Replace everything `int` with `double`, both support the same operators (%, +, -, *)

Comment: Tried that, doesn't compile, cannot convert double to int

Answer (score 0):

When you said

> I've tried rewriting all the Int's as Double's but that doesn't work.

this should only apply to the data you manipulate, not the array indexes. If that doesn't work, please post the faulty code and we can help you with that.

You have to separate the array indexes and sizes (like: n, c, d, etc.) which are always of type int from the values you manipulate( array[], swap, median, mid, etc.) which will be of type double

```
int n, c, d;
double swap, sum=0;
...
n = in.nextInt();
double array[] = new double[n];
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple problems I can spot: First cast your array as a `double` array. Second use `in.nextDouble()` rather than `in.nextInt()`. Third, prompt for `doubles` as your assignment states. Finally, array indexes, sizes, and counts should be `ints`.